# Do we have to define url anywhere while querying from AZURE SEARCH index

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

Is AZURE search using c# is based only on ServiceName, IndexName and APIKEY.

Why aren't we using the URL?

I have looked into many document regarding the everything lead by APIKEY only. 
Then what is the use of URL?

Because while querying from Post master we are using URL and Service version also but not while querying form C#.

Comment: are you using some kind of C# client library (e.g. provided by Microsoft) to talk to the search service? I'd guess maybe the URL is hard-coded in there (or least pre-provided but configurable). The library/SDK is likely to just be a wrapper around the HTTP requests.

Comment: Yes, I installed Microsoft.Azure.Search nuget package.

Comment: In that case then, to me it makes logical sense for it not to ask you to provide a URL which the developers of the package already know. It's always going to make a HTTP request to the same base URL, and the package will be coded to know the specific URLs for each endpoint which the package supports. I don't know this for sure, but it seems logical. Most of Microsoft's code packages are open-source these days so you could probably look it up on GitHub if you're interested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Knowing the search service name is the same as having the API URL.
From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/#calling-the-apis), once you have the search service name, you can construct the URL like this:

`GET https://[search service name].search.windows.net/indexes?api-version=2019-05-06`

Comment: The client SDK for Azure Search can construct the URL internally based on search service name and use that to send http requests. This simplifies the application code which doesn't have to construct the url itself.